# Get data from stats channel request api telegram

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

I want to get statistics data channel from telegram api. I wrote and run this code but get an error:
*telethon.errors.rpcerrorlist.ChatAdminRequiredError: Chat admin privileges are required to do that in the specified chat (for example, to send a message in a channel which is not yours), or invalid permission
s used for the channel or group (caused by GetBroadcastStatsRequest)*
Please help me check and fix it. Thank a lot !
p/s: This is my channel

````
import configparser
from telethon.tl.types import ChannelParticipantsSearch
from telethon.tl.functions.channels import GetFullChannelRequest
from telethon import functions, types
from telethon.tl.functions.stats import GetBroadcastStatsRequest
from telethon.tl.types import PeerUser, PeerChat, PeerChannel
from telethon.tl.types import InputChannel
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read("config.ini")


api_id = config['Telegram']['api_id']
api_hash = config['Telegram']['api_hash']

api_hash = str(api_hash)

phone = config['Telegram']['phone']
username = config['Telegram']['username']
channel = 'https://t.me/testapi2607'
id_channel = 1523534046
access_hash = 7456721436474437
client = TelegramClient(username, api_id, api_hash)
async def main():
    await client.start()
    print("Client Created")
    # Ensure you're authorized
    if await client.is_user_authorized() == False:
        await client.send_code_request(phone)
        try:
            await client.sign_in(phone, input('Enter the code: '))
        except SessionPasswordNeededError:
            await client.sign_in(password=input('Password: '))
    me = await client.get_me()
    await client.get_entity(PeerChannel(1523534046))
    my_channel = InputChannel(id_channel, access_hash)
    result = await client(functions.stats.GetBroadcastStatsRequest(channel = my_channel, dark=True))
    print(str(result))
with client:
    client.loop.run_until_complete(main())```
````

Comment: I believe your channel needs to have a certain amount of members, otherwise this error is raised.

Comment: it's a test channel and just have 2 members. Is this problem ?

Comment: Yes. I don't remember the amount of member it needs, but it probably has to be over a thousand.